# How to get program to print decimal value when taking average?

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, double, wrapper

The question says:

- Debug the code provided in the starter file so it does the following:
- Creates two Integer objects x and y, and initializes them as null
- Prints the values of x and y (should result in the output "null null")
- Sets x and y to inputs entered by the user
- Finds the average of the two values and stores this in a Double value avg
- Prints a sentence as shown in the sample run with the values of x, y and the average

Right now I have:

```java
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer x = null;
    Integer y = null;

    System.out.print(x + " ");
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println("Enter values:");
    x = scan.nextInt();
    y = scan.nextInt();

    Double avg = ((double)((x + y) / 2));
    System.out.println("Average of " + x + " and " + y + " is " + (double) avg);
```

Right now it prints:

```
null null
Enter values:
5
12
Average of 5 and 12 is 8.0
```

But I need it to print:

```
null null
Enter values:
>5
>12
Average of 5 and 12 is 8.5
```

Comment: You are not _calculating_ a double average, you're calculating an int average and then storing it in a double.

Comment: Move your cast to double closer to (X+y)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should looks like this. In your case you just make division with integers with losing precision and then cast to double.

```
Double avg = (double) (x + y) / 2;
System.out.println("Average of " + x + " and " + y + " is " +  avg);
```

Here is result

```
null null
Enter values:
5
12
Average of 5 and 12 is 8.5
```

and do not forget to close scanner after all

```
scan.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the way your parentheses are set up. The correct answer would be:

```
Double avg = ((double) (x + y) / 2.0);
```

You were casting the result of the integer operation as a double, rather than casting the operation itself as a double.

Comment: It may be `Double avg = (x + y) / 2.0;`